# Set hibernate dialect for jpa in YML

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, configuration

I tried to set hibernate dialect for jpa in YML,

checked many topics, but it does not set:

```
spring:
 datasource:
  hikari:
   allow-pool-suspension: true
   connection-timeout: 1000
name: testDb
jpa:
 database: h2
 generate-ddl: false
 database-platform: h2
 package-to-scan: com.x.model
  properties:
   hibernate:
    dialect: com.x.data.core.hibernate.dialect.ExtendedH2Dialect

h2:
 console:
  enabled: true
  path: /h2
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

what is `com.x.data.core.hibernate.dialect.ExtendedH2Dialect` ? You have to use dialect as `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

below is the sample

```
server:
port: 8096

spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:~/test
    username: sa
    password: 
    h2:
      console:
        enabled: true
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: false
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Note:
I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` 2.0.5