# Why am I obtaining this "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException" in a Spring Boot project using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am pretty new in Spring Boot and I am finding some difficulties trying to configure JPA on a **Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE** project connecting to a **MariaDB** database.

Here the Github repository link of the mentioned project: https://github.com/AndreaNobili/SpringBoot-Excel-API

I try to explain my situation in details:

Into my **MariaDB** server have a database named **db_test** containing a single table named **order** and having this structure:

```
'id',              'bigint(20)',   'NO', 'PRI', NULL,   'auto_increment'
'name',            'varchar(255)', 'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'address',         'varchar(255)', 'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'product',         'varchar(255)', 'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'order_date_time', 'datetime',     'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
'quantity',        'tinyint(4)',   'NO', '',    NULL,   ''
```

Then I have this model class named **Order** mapping the previous table:

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String fullName;
    private String address;
    private String product;

    @Column(name = "order_date_time")
    private String orderDate;

    private Double quantity;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public Double getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Double quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

I defined this JPA **OrderRepository** interface extending the **CrudRepository** interface:

```
package com.springboot.excelapi.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.springboot.excelapi.dto.Order;

public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Integer> {

}
```

Then I created a service class calling the previous repository (to implement the business logic service layer):

First I definied an **OrderService** interface:

```
package com.springboot.excelapi.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.springboot.excelapi.dto.Order;

public interface OrderService {

    public List<Order> getOrdersList();
}
```

Then I implemented the **OrderServiceImpl** concrete class implementing the previous interface:

```
package com.springboot.excelapi.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.springboot.excelapi.dto.Order;
import com.springboot.excelapi.repository.OrderRepository;

@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orderRepository;

    public List<Order> getOrdersList() {

        List<Order> result = (List<Order>) orderRepository.findAll();

        //List<Order> result = new ArrayList<Order>();

        return result;
    }

}
```

As you can see this class is annotated as **@Service** and into is body I am autowiring the previous **OrderRepository** interface used to perform my query.

Into the **src/main/resources** folder there is the **application.yml** configuration file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Spring Boot Excel API
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/db_test
    username: admin
    password: password
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1000
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1

  jpa:
    hibernate: 
      ddl-auto: none
```

It contains the information related to the MariaDB database connection and the **JPA** configuration. At the moment **ddl-auto** is set to **none** because I want to avoid that changes in my model class doesn't affect my database tables structure.

Finnally I have this **JUnit** test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "no-liquibase" })
public class ExcelResourceIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    OrderServiceImpl orderService;

    @Test
    public void getOrdersListServiceTest() {    
        List<Order> ordersList = orderService.getOrdersList();

        assertThat(ordersList).isNotEmpty();
    }

}
```

It contains the **getOrdersListRepositoryTest()** test method that I am usign to test the previous service.

Performing this method in debug mode, it enter into the **getOrdersList()** service method but when it try to execute this line:

```
List<Order> result = (List<Order>) orderRepository.findAll();
```

it go into error and I obtain an exception.

Into the console I obtain this error message:

```
2020-03-23 08:39:19.310  INFO 3781 --- [           main] c.s.e.i.ExcelResourceIntegrationTest     : Started ExcelResourceIntegrationTest in 5.136 seconds (JVM running for 6.459)
2020-03-23 08:39:19.719  WARN 3781 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2020-03-23 08:39:19.719 ERROR 3781 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn:36) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order order0_' at line 1
Query is: select order0_.id as id1_0_, order0_.address as address2_0_, order0_.name as name3_0_, order0_.order_date_time as order_da4_0_, order0_.product as product5_0_, order0_.quantity as quantity6_0_ from order order0_
2020-03-23 08:39:19.879  INFO 3781 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-23 08:39:19.882  INFO 3781 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-23 08:39:19.888  INFO 3781 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-03-23 08:39:19.907  INFO 3781 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

So, from what I can understand Hibernate it is trying to perform this query:

```
select order0_.id as id1_0_, order0_.address as address2_0_, order0_.name as name3_0_, order0_.order_date_time as order_da4_0_, order0_.product as product5_0_, order0_.quantity as quantity6_0_ from order order0_
```

it seems to me pretty strange: why **order0**?

Into the stacktrace I am ontaining this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.springboot.excelapi.service.OrderServiceImpl.getOrdersList(OrderServiceImpl.java:21)
    at com.springboot.excelapi.integration.ExcelResourceIntegrationTest.getOrdersListServiceTest(ExcelResourceIntegrationTest.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:36) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order order0_' at line 1
Query is: select order0_.id as id1_0_, order0_.address as address2_0_, order0_.name as name3_0_, order0_.order_date_time as order_da4_0_, order0_.product as product5_0_, order0_.quantity as quantity6_0_ from order order0_
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:139)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:101)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwAndLogException(ExceptionMapper.java:77)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MariaDbStatement.java:224)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:232)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:177)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order order0_' at line 1
Query is: select order0_.id as id1_0_, order0_.address as address2_0_, order0_.name as name3_0_, order0_.order_date_time as order_da4_0_, order0_.product as product5_0_, order0_.quantity as quantity6_0_ from order order0_
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1098)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1030)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:985)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:161)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:223)
    ... 98 more
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

I attach also my **pom.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>excel-api-SOC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Excel API with Spring Boot 2</name>
    <description>Spring Boot - working with Excel API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start of excel dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End of excel dependencies -->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Start DB connectivity dependencies -->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End DB connectivity dependencies -->

        <!-- JPA dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: this is pretty long and I didn't reproduce it, but maybe the `dialect` setting is missing? That could cause hibernate to generate the wrong SQL statement (`as` is missing?)

Comment: see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546758/set-hibernate-dialect-for-jpa-in-yml/52547242 ,

Comment: the maria DB dialect is probably as per this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066024/what-is-the-mariadb-dialect-class-name-for-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is named `order`, which is a keyword in ***all*** SQL dialects (*hint:* `ORDER BY` clause). Do not name the table `order`, unless you want to always have to quote the name when writing SQL statements.

You can still name your Java class `Order`, but you should name the table something else, e.g. `customer_order`, `product_order`, `order_detail`, or something like that.